# how to launch java class before MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I am creating a project that need to run java classes before run and launch Main Activity. my java class are : Bluetooth.java, register.java, DatabaseHelper.java. the order of program that i need to run : Bluetooth > register> MainActivity. MainActivity is the only Activity that had layout. what i had already done :

1. i deleted setContentView in Bluetooth and register since they don't have layout.
2. i used intent to refer one activity to another. bluetooth to register then register to MainActivity
3. i changed AndroidManifest
   here's the code :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.windows8.registerlogin">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

   <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <activity android:name=".Bluetooth" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity android:name=".Register"
       android:label="@string/app_name"/>
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"/>
   </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

   After I launch my program, it suddenly shutdown before i can do anything. 
    can you tell me what's wrong with my program? or is there something i left out? thanks. (it seems i cannot post my logcat here)

Comment: Make an empty activity (a loading screen) which waits until all the necessary components become loaded and then proceed to the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate` of `Bluetooth` do something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            initBluetooth();    //Perform any operations
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            startActivity(Bluetooth.this, register.java);
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

Use similar code in register.java.

This is the solution to your exact problem. However it is not the ideal way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Using a launcher activity is a good idea, but make sure to not lock the UI thread by initializing stuff in `onCreate` or leak a context to an anonymous AsyncTask. 
Based on what you've described, Bluetooth and Register don't need to be activities.  Assuming that is right and you can make them standalone classes, here's an example of how that would look:

```
private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> loader = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.launcher_activity);
    loader = new LoadStuff(this);
    loader.execute();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if( loader != null ) {
        loader.cancel(true);
        loader = null;
    }
}

static class LoadStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    WeakReferences<Activity> context;

    LoadStuff(Activity context) {
        this.context = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // assuming they're singletons
        Bluetooth.initialize();
        Register.initialize();
        return 0; // or pass an error code if these fail
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        Activity c = context.get();
        if( c != null ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(c, MainActivity.class);
            c.startActivity(intent);
            c.finish(); // don't let the user come back to this screen
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, both bluetooth and register are activities but i'm not using their layout. i deleted their layout.

Comment: If there's no layout, why do they even need to be Activities? An Activity is a GUI element, for showing something to the user. If you're not doing that you shouldn't need to make them Activities at all...

Comment: i was using them as an activity because i create my project based on check every activity to make sure my program is working. for example in activity bluetooth i can check whether my data was received by showing it in layout. i though if everything was checked and working it's easier to combine those program.

Comment: I would recommend not making it an Activity. If it's an Activity, you are not guaranteed that it will stick around (Android system can kill off Activities that aren't displayed to preserve system resources). A better idea would be to make some sort of "BluetoothManager" class that gets the application context, and if you can't test it as-is with Espresso (or similar) make a "BluetoothDisplay" activity to check the values. An Activity with no layout will just show a blank screen to the user, who will likely assume your app has frozen

Answer (score 0):

Call Bluetooth class from application class. like this

```
public class AppTest extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   //Call your bluetooth class
}
}
```

And add you application class name in androidmanifest file:

```
<application
    android:name=".AppTest">
```

Answer (score -1):

You should post the error you get but I will present you the most probable solution.
Your app probably crashes since the class `Bluetooth` is not extending activity yet is flagged as an activity.

Create a launcher activity that will have a loading screen just to show your user that the app is running. This activity since it will be the first can call the classes that you want and only then can you start your main activity.

So the onCreate() method will look like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.launcher_activity);

    new Bluetooth();
    new Register();

    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```